# NLog Logger Stops Logging to File After Changing System Time

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, logging, nlog

One of our testers here managed to get our application to stop logging by changing the system date and time forward and backwards a few times. Of course, I have him working on trying to recreate it and remember the sequence of events that got him there.

I'm using NLog 2.0 on .Net 4 and Windows 7.

1. The problem persisted across application restarts.
2. The logger created a new file and started logging again after I deleted the existing log file

Has anyone else out there run into this?

Comment: I forgot to add the following details.
1. The problem persisted across application restarts.
2. The logger created a new file and started logging again after I deleted the existing log file.

Comment: you may want to log this issue to NLog's creator..